# Could not obtain a WAC access token - excel worksheet

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-api

When trying to access a Excel workbook getting the following error,
"message": "Could not obtain a WAC access token.".

The permissions given [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShEwf.png)

Any ideas???

Comment: Could you please share the code you are using?

Comment: Please share the API call that you're using and the detailed error code (with requestid, timestamp)